# Email client that allows arbitrary sender adresses

Tags: email, imap

I am looking for an email client that allows me to specify an arbitrary sender adress each time I send a message without explicitly creating a new identity. Especially when I hit reply to, it should use the recipient adress of the original email as sender. I am looking for Linux and Windows GUIs (e.g. Thunderbird) and/or Webmail (e.g. Roundcube). Open-source software is strongly preferred.

I have a domain, example.com where I catch all email. Let's say I buy something from a webshop that requires an email, I use awebshop@example.com to sign up. That way once they start spamming me or leaked my email I can simply block it. Now let's say I want to contact or respond to their customer support via email. Then I would like to also use awebshop@example.com to send a message. Currently with either Thunderbird or Roundcube I have to create a new Identity I am looking for a way to make that more simple.

Clarification: I want to keep the emails on my server. I am not looking for a service but a software that I can run either on my server and/or my computers that connects to the server via IMAP.

Comment: Hello Zulan and thanks for your question. I have removed the ["optional"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/271/60) tags [tag:windows]/ [tag:linux]/[tag:web-apps] (because you don’t require a solution to run on all these platforms) and [tag:open-source] (because you do *prefer* but not *require* a solution to be FLOSS). Feel free to add tags back in case they are requirements.

Comment: Hmm... Just to clarify, I meant [this](http://www.google.com/intx/en/enterprise/apps/business/products/gmail/) service for accessing emails from your personal domain.

Comment: i'm not sure because I didn't try myself but this Thunderbird feature could help you achieve what you want : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/configuring-email-aliases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the results of my personal research.

***GUIs:***

**KMail**: Very good support

- Freetext from field
- Multiple fixed identities can be created with one primary and associated emails
- When replying to a mail it will select the identity that has the receiver email associated and send from the primary email of that identity
- Custom sent folder can be set for each identity

**Thunderbird**: Good support (since [this fix](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=87987))

- Custom from address can be selected
- Multiple identities can be created
- When replying, a custom from address is not used

***WEB Interfaces:***

**Horde** poor support

- Multiple identities can be created
- Easier if `$conf[user][verify_from_addr]` disabled (Horde/User Capabilities and Constraints)
- Custom sent folder needs to be selected per mail

**Roundcube** poor support

- Multiple identities can be created
- Custom sent folder needs to be selected per mail
- The correct identity is automatically selected in a reply, if the mail has been sent to it and the identity exists

**SOGo** no support

- On the [Roadmap](http://www.sogo.nu/development/roadmap.html) "Email identities support in the web mail interface"

Comment: I added the reply behavior for Roundcube (which is nice) and Thunderbird (poor). I hope this corresponds with your experience?

Comment: @sebix, thanks for your Answer. I can confirm it for Roundcube, but actually selecting the right non-default identity works for me in Thunderbird as well (31.0 on Windows7 64 bit)

Comment: Thanks for your check, you are right, sry :) *hiding behind the last edit*

Comment: Finally what do you use now? Did you try to use Horde? It doesn't allow auto-fill sender field from received email during reply?

Comment: I primarily use Thunderbird and it's fine. Don't really do anything with web interfaces these days, haven't really looked into Horde since I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness and in case you drop your GUI requirement, [mutt](http://mutt.org) handles multiple from addresses easily. See i.e. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12158201/2015768) or maybe [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33458/71928).

Answer (score 0):

A current version of Thunderbird with the SmtpSelect and Virtual Identity allows you do exactly what you ask for.

I create new From-addresses in every mail (I have hundreds of them) but only have a couple of accounts and aliases for each account (that I never edit after the initial setup).

I am looking for a similar solution for mobile devices!

Comment: Since [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=87987) was fixed in Thunderbird it works well even without addons! No Idea about mobile though, sorry.