# Email client for catch-all accounts

Tags: email-client

I own several domains that I use catch-all accounts for. I'm looking for an email client that will send replies from the account it was sent to.

I have tried Inky, Outlook, Thunderbird, and several more.

I am a developer and have experience with SMTP and IMAP and considered writing my own, but if someone's already done it, then I'd prefer to avoid the headache myself.

I don't really care about a fancy interface or anything like that, I literally just want to reply to emails in my catchall account. Windows preferred, but at this point I don't have a problem setting up a Linux VM just for this.

Comment: Assuming you are manually replying Thunderbird does this fine if the setup is correct. Automatic replies is a little harder.

Comment: @SteveBarnes it's all manual... I'll revisit Thunderbird. I got Inky to work with aliases but I don't want to have to setup a ton of aliases... it's working for short-term now though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email client that allows arbitrary sender adresses](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10285/email-client-that-allows-arbitrary-sender-adresses)

Comment: hi, Timothy! What solution have you chosen finally?

Comment: @Suncatcher still no good solution :( I plan to try cypht (self-hosted webmail) soon, but I'm not sure if it'll really do everything I want either. It's still on my to do list to write my own to just do what I want it to do, but for now I just deal with basic webmail and manually setting up aliases as needed.